# IndexOutOfBounds ao preencher uma AbstractTableModel

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel

Tenho uma `AbstractTableModel` que possui uma `List` preenchida através de um método que busca os dados no banco de dados. O método que preenche a List possui duas sobrecargas: uma sem nenhum parâmetro(que busca todos os dados) e outra com um parâmetro de busca(para buscar um dado específico).

Quando eu preencho minha `AbstractTableModel` usando a `List` preenchida através do método sem parâmetros, eu consigo trazer todos os dados na tela. Porém quando preencho usando a List preenchida através do método com parâmetro de busca(ou seja, quando eu tento buscar um dado específico no banco), ele me retorna uma:

> IndexOutOfBoundException index 1 size 1.

Minha classe AbstractTableModel:

```
public class ProdutoVendaTableModel extends AbstractTableModel{

private ProdutoControle prodCtrl = new ProdutoControle();
private String colunas[] = {"Produto", "Valor", "Marca", "Gênero"};

private List<Produto> produtos;

public void fillLista(){
    produtos = prodCtrl.listar(busca);
}

public void fillLista(String busca){
    produtos = prodCtrl.listar(busca);
}

@Override
public String getColumnName(int coluna) {
    return colunas[coluna];
}

@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    return prodCtrl.listar().size();
}

@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    return colunas.length;
}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int linha, int coluna) {
    switch(coluna){
        case 0:
            return produtos.get(linha).getDescricao(); //nessa linha ocorre a exceção
        case 1:
            return produtos.get(linha).getValor_unitario();
        case 2:
            return produtos.get(linha).getMarca();
        case 3:
            return produtos.get(linha).getGenero();
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

Aqui os métodos da minha camada de controle que servem apenas como mensageiros entre a AbstractTableModel e a camada DAO:

```
public List<Produto> listar(){
    return pDAO.buscar();
}

public List<Produto> listar(String busca){
    return pDAO.buscar(busca);
}
```

Abaixo minha camada DAO onde eu busco os dados no banco:

```
public List<Produto> buscar(){
    con = ConexaoBanco.getConexao();
    sql = "SELECT * FROM view_produtos";
    produtos = new ArrayList<>();

    try{
        stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);

        rs = stmt.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()){
            marca = new Marca();
            marca.setId(rs.getInt("mid"));
            marca.setDescricao(rs.getString("mdescricao"));

            genero = new Genero();
            genero.setId(rs.getInt("gid"));
            genero.setDescricao(rs.getString("gdescricao"));

            fornecedor = new Fornecedor();
            fornecedor.setId(rs.getInt("fid"));
            fornecedor.setRazao_social(rs.getString("razao_social"));
            fornecedor.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
            fornecedor.setTelefone(rs.getString("telefone"));
            fornecedor.setCnpj(rs.getInt("cnpj"));
            fornecedor.setAtivo(rs.getInt("fativo"));

            produto = new Produto(marca, genero, fornecedor);
            produto.setId(rs.getInt("pid"));
            produto.setDescricao(rs.getString("pdescricao"));
            produto.setValor_unitario(rs.getFloat("valor_unitario"));
            produto.setEstoque_min(rs.getInt("estoque_min"));
            produto.setEstoque_max(rs.getInt("estoque_max"));
            produto.setAtivo(rs.getInt("pativo"));

            produtos.add(produto);
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex, "Erro", 0);
    }
    finally{
        ConexaoBanco.fechar(con, stmt, rs);
    }
    return produtos;
}

public List<Produto> buscar(String busca){
    con = ConexaoBanco.getConexao();
    sql = "SELECT * FROM view_produtos WHERE pdescricao LIKE '%"+busca+"%'";
    produtos = new ArrayList<>();

    try{
        stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);

        rs = stmt.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()){
            marca = new Marca();
            marca.setId(rs.getInt("mid"));
            marca.setDescricao(rs.getString("mdescricao"));

            genero = new Genero();
            genero.setId(rs.getInt("gid"));
            genero.setDescricao(rs.getString("gdescricao"));

            fornecedor = new Fornecedor();
            fornecedor.setId(rs.getInt("fid"));
            fornecedor.setRazao_social(rs.getString("razao_social"));
            fornecedor.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
            fornecedor.setTelefone(rs.getString("telefone"));
            fornecedor.setCnpj(rs.getInt("cnpj"));
            fornecedor.setAtivo(rs.getInt("fativo"));

            produto = new Produto(marca, genero, fornecedor);
            produto.setId(rs.getInt("pid"));
            produto.setDescricao(rs.getString("pdescricao"));
            produto.setValor_unitario(rs.getFloat("valor_unitario"));
            produto.setEstoque_min(rs.getInt("estoque_min"));
            produto.setEstoque_max(rs.getInt("estoque_max"));
            produto.setAtivo(rs.getInt("pativo"));

            produtos.add(produto);
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex, "Erro", 0);
    }
    finally{
        ConexaoBanco.fechar(con, stmt, rs);
    }
    return produtos;
}
```

O evento clique do botão de pesquisa na tela:

```
private void btnPesquisaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            

    prodTable = new ProdutoVendaTableModel();
    prodTable.fillLista(busca);
    jtProdutos.setModel(prodTable);
}
```

Quando eu clico no botão de pesquisa com a caixa de texto vazia os dados aparecem normalmente, mas se eu tento de fato pesquisar algo, caio na exceção. Alguma ideia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu código não é testável, então não da pra afirmar com exatidão o motivo do erro, mas acredito que seja esta a causa:

altere este trecho:

```
@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    return prodCtrl.listar().size();
}
```

para:

```
@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    return produtos.size();
}
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo, deu certo! Só uma dúvida quanto ao seu comentário, o que seria de fato um código testável?

Comment: @LucasDurigan seria um **[mcve]**, que é uma versão do seu código que qualquer um poderia compilar e executar para ver onde o problema se origina. Neste caso o problema estava no código, mas as vezes costuma estar em outros lugares, até mesmo no banco. Por isso que é importante isolar o problema, fazendo o código com alguns exemplos feitos na mao ao inves de buscado do banco, quando faço isso, geralmente encontro o erro mais facil.